# How to control the highlight effect when opening a feature layer's popup?

Tags: popup, feature-layer, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

By default, when a featureLayer has a popupTemplate specified, clicking on the feature will open the popup and also apply a highlight effect to the feature, as in the [Intro to PopupTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/intro-popuptemplate/live/) example - note the blue highlight around the polygon:

[image: screenshot showing highlighted polygon]

How can this effect be controlled? In other words, how can we modify the symbol used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the highlight for all popups using view.highlightOptions - see https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#highlightOptions

```
const view = new MapView({
  map: map,
  highlightOptions: {
    color: [255, 255, 0, 1],
    haloOpacity: 0.9,
    fillOpacity: 0.2
  }
});
```